# How to change "male" or "female" to "his" or "her"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I wanted to try out something and started making a code that just asks questions and after you've answered them, it puts out a sentence about you. Though when I ask " Are you a male or a female? " I cant change the answer to go from "male" = "his" and "female" = "her". And when I tried to do something it says name "male" not defined.

```
def namePerson():
    name = input('Whats your name? ' )
    gender = input('Are you a male or a female? ')

    if gender == male:
        sex = his
    else:
        sex = her

    birth_year = input('What was the year you were born in?' )
    age = 2020 - int(birth_year)
    color = input('Whats your favorite color?' )
    return "{} is {} years old, and {} favorite color is {}.".format(name, int(age), sex, color)

print(namePerson())

NameError: name 'male' is not defined
```

I've tried searching, but the posts were posted very long ago, and on Python 2.7.

Comment: The error message mentioned, that male is not defined. In the line `if gender == male` it tries to compare gender to the variable name, which is indeed not defined. In your case you want to compare gender with the string `male`: `if gernder == 'male'`

Comment: your equality `if gender == male`, requires the `male` variable, you want to use a string (`"male"`). That is why there is a `NameError`. For replacing values in a string you can use the `replace` method. The pattern is `string.replace(old, new)`, any case use: `gender.replace('male', 'his')`.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you understand the difference between string values and variable names.

`male` is not defined because you are referring to a non-existant variable named `male`. To specify that male is a string and not the name of a variable, you need to use quotes.

Your code should read:

```py
if gender == 'male':
    sex = 'his'
else:
    sex = 'her'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can this:

```
def namePerson():
name = input('Whats your name? ' )
gender = int(input('Are you a male(1) or a female(2)?'))

if gender == 1:
    sex = "his"
else:
    sex = "her"

birth_year = input('What was the year you were born in?' )
age = 2020 - int(birth_year)
color = input('Whats your favorite color?' )
return "{} is {} years old, and {} favorite color is {}.".format(name, int(age), sex, color)

print(namePerson())
```